# Python Reportlab Fonts PDF

Tags: python, pdf, reportlab

I have a problem  displaying  pdf with Adobe Reader or PDF Xchange Viewer, generated using  python and reportlab. 
When I open pdf with Adobe Reader all I get are this checkbox characters, but there is no problem when I open pdf file with Google Chrome. So it's a windows problem.

Here is code just in case

```
from reportlab.lib.pagesizes import letter, A4
from reportlab.pdfgen import canvas

from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfmetrics 
from reportlab.pdfbase.ttfonts import TTFont 
import datetime


date=datetime.date.today().strftime("%d-%m-%y")

canvas = canvas.Canvas("form22.pdf", pagesize=letter)
canvas.setLineWidth(.3)
pdfmetrics.registerFont(TTFont("Serbian","fontscirglasd.ttf"))

canvas.setFont('Serbian', 12)

canvas.drawString(30,750,'РЕПУБЛИКА СРБИЈА'.encode("utf-8"))
canvas.drawString(30,735,'РЕПУБЛИЧКИ ГЕОДЕТСКИ ЗАВОД'.encode('utf-8'))

canvas.save()
```